# DataGrid spell checking: how to add a custom dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, spell-checking, .net-4.6.1

I have a datagrid with spell checking enabled on one of the columns. The spell checker uses the default dictionary, however I would like to add a custom dictionary so that the spell checker has access to the domain specific terms added by the user.

The column is defined as follows:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgcComments" Header="Comment" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Comment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange}">
        <DataGridColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,2" />
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,2" />
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="4000" />
                <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    ...
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I know I can't add the dictionary in the xaml - SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries doesn't have a setter, only add and remove methods. Is there a way to add the dictionary in the code behind? I'm stumped; I can't work out how to get access to the TextBox editing element in order to call TextBox.SpellCheck.CustomDictionary.Add().

Comment: Have you tried [SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem as stated in question above. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx

uri description - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" 
<DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgcComments" Header="Comment" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Comment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange}">
            <DataGridColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,2" />
                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,2" />
                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="4000" />
                    <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                   <Setter Property="SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <sys:Uri>pack://application:,,,/customwords.lex</sys:Uri>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but the specific error in this case is "The property CustomDictionaries does not have an accessible setter".

Comment: The specific example that you linked to was working with a RichTextBox, which appears to have access to the custom dictionary in a different way: `code`<RichTextBox Margin="38,18,40,0" Name="richTextBox1" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" >
    <SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
        <!-- customwords.lex is included as a content file-->
        <sys:Uri>pack://application:,,,/customwords.lex</sys:Uri>
    </SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
</RichTextBox>`code`